# Decimal places in a monitor

Tags: netlogo

I have set decimal places in a Netlogo Monitor to 4.  Numbers that end in 0's get truncated  (3.4500 appears as 3.45, 3.4550 appears as 3.455). Is there some way to retain the 4 decimal appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we define:

```
to-report zero-pad [n places]
  let result (word precision n places)
  if not is-number? position "." result [
    set result (word result ".")
  ]
  let padding-amount position "." result - length result + places + 1
  let padding reduce word fput "" n-values padding-amount [0]
  report (word result padding)
end
```

Let's see if it works:

```
observer> show zero-pad 1.2 3
observer: "1.200"
observer> show zero-pad 1.2468 2
observer: "1.25"
```

Looks good. So now, in the monitor, instead of just `x`, write e.g. `zero-pad x 4` if you want four decimal places.